# How to get 8-bit of each byte from byte array in java?

Tags: java

I have the byte array of an image. I need to process each of these bytes of the array. To process these bytes I need its 8-bit binary value. How should I go about it. I am using java for my processing.
I have used the following code for it but it seems to be wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length; i++) {
        byte bytegen = (byte) bytearray[i];
        String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytegen& 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        ss[i] = s1;
```

Comment: Maybe not related, but don't forget that Java types are all **signed** and that includes the byte type.

Comment: A `byte` *is* the 8 bits. If you need to "process" the bits, see [The Java™ Tutorials - Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), or any [bit manipulation](https://www.google.com/search?q=bit-manipulation) guide on the web.

Comment: neither seems to answer my question as to how to get 8 bit from each byte.could you probable give me an example code